# Using JMeter with iframes

Tags: iframe, automated-tests, jmeter

I have a test plan for our UAT environment using JMeter and part of the user journey involves hitting a page with an iframe to accept payment using a payment provider.

The payment provider from the iframe has three stages:

1. Select payment type (VISA, MasterCard etc.)
2. Enter payment details (Card number, expiry etc.)
3. Enter status code (Approved or Declined because it is a test environment)

How do I implement these iframe requests using JMeter?

Comment: Sorry for my silly question but what means "iframe request"? Should it send ajax request when you are interacting with iframe on web page? Doesn't recording controller capture requests from your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and record it first. Use either JMeter proxy: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder
Or BlazeMeter's Chrome extension: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/231479-chrome-extension

You will then need to clean an parametrize your script. Take a look at CSV data set config: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

If you need some video tutorials to do just that, take a look here: http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series

Comment: Thanks - I just tried using the BlazeMeter Chrome extension and it failed to pick up the iframe data. I suspect this is also the case for the Test Script Recorder, but I shall give it a try regardless.

Comment: I can confirm that the Test Script Recorder also failed to work correctly with an iframe

Comment: Yap, a known bug. Should be fixed in the next release due next week.

Comment: This is a known bug in BlazeMeter's extension or JMeter? Thanks

Comment: The new version of BlazeMeter's Chrome extension appears to have resolved the issues I was having.

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet is probably BlazeMeter's JMeter chrome extension, though you need to change one of the settings.

When you are browsing a site that uses iframes, AJAX calls, JS based requests (etc) you need to into the "Advanced Options" in the extension and uncheck "Record Only Top Level Requests".

The extension will now record EVERY request your browser is making, so be sure to close any other tabs you have open.

The Test Script Recorder might be failing due to security issues on the domain in the iframe. The advantage of using the chrome extension is that it doesn't care if the requests are secure or not.

Comment: The BlazeMeter extension still fails to pick up the GET & POSTs within the iframe with Record Only Top Level Requests disabled.

Comment: can you provide a URL you are trying to test?

Comment: It's behind a firewall sorry.